# Adding spaces before or after parentheses - Python

Tags: python

I need to write a program that will split a paragraph into sentences and add spaces before and after commas, punctuation marks, and parentheses. However, if it has a name like         d-(−)-lactic acid, I don't insert spaces. This is what I have so far:

```
import re
import string
message = input("Enter a file name: ")
hand = open(message)
x = re.findall('\S+\(\S+', line.rstrip())
y = ''.join(x)
for line in hand:
        fp = re.sub('(?<! )(?=[.,!?()])|(?<=[.,!?()])(?! )', r' ', line)
        sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', fp)
        if y in line:
            pass
        else:
            fp = re.sub('(?<! )(?=[.,!?()])|(?<=[.,!?()])(?! )', r' ', sentences)
            sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', fp)
        print(*sentences, sep="\n")
```

I'm not sure how to account for the names that are similar to d-(-)-lactic acid.

Edit: Here's the example text:

CD5 was found associated with the Src homology 2 (SH2) domain containing hematopoietic phosphotyrosine phosphatase SHP-1 in both Jurkat cells and normal phytohemagglutinin-expanded T lymphoblasts. SATB1 also targets ACF1 and ISWI (subunits of chromatin-accessibility complex (CHRAC) and ACF nucleosome mobilizing complexes) to this specific site and regulates ACF1 receptor positioning over seven kilobases.Taken together, these results indicate that the Ras-interacting region on AF-6 is structurally similar to that on Raf-1 and on RalGDS and that AF-6 interacts with activated Ras and L-(+)-Tartaric acid in vivo.

So the term I'm having issues with here is L-(+)-Tartaric acid. Spaces aren't supposed to be inserted in that term.

Comment: Could you show us a sample of your file and the expected output, please? I used this piece of text, that I found in a medical website:
"D-lactic acidosis is an uncommon and challenging form of metabolic acidosis that may develop in short bowel syndrome. It has been documented exclusively in case reports and small case series.
METHODS:We performed a review of the literature in the National Library of Medicine and Excerpta Medica databases."
I executed your code and the output was every single letter in a different line.

Comment: Like @powerPixie rightly mentioned, please provide at least 2-3 paragraphs for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for adding spaces before or after parentheses:

```
  import re
  import string
  message = input("Enter a file name: ")
  hand = open(message)
  txt=hand.read()
  sentences = re.split(r' *[\.][\'"\)\]]* *', txt)
  for stuff in sentences:
          x = re.search('^\w+([-]?\w+)*\w+([\.()-]?\w+)*\w+([-]?\w+)+$',stuff)
          if x:
            print(x)
          else:
            stuff = re.sub('([.,!?()])', r' \1 ', stuff)
            stuff = re.sub('\txt{2,}', ' ', stuff)
            print(stuff)
```